# Starting a new line in SO topic comments

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

A new line can be started in a question text box by double enter or double space. But... how to start a new text line in Comments to any SO topic?

And, how to start a new line in Code section of such Comments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't.

Comment: While the answer was apparently given in the above linked thread, I join these members who suggested to add "new line" formatting to comments for the same reasons as they stated. Its also interesting to note, the original question didn't seem to popup in search results, while posting this one, unless I missed it.

Comment: Comments are supposed to be rather short one liners, we don't want to be able to allow formatting to that level.

Comment: I give you an example. If someone answered my question on SO, and then I corrected the question code to reflect the solution for others benefit, I want to post such code as Comment rather than as Answer, since it wasn't me who answered the question, so it would look unethical for me to claim the answer.

Comment: @JonH - I conceive short comments that would be more readable if a newline were allowed for. E.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776489/find-which-file-was-used-by-an-include-directive?noredirect=1#comment96418774_54776489).

Comment: If you want short one liners limit the character count. But if you want to make a structured reply new lines are VERY useful. Is there a way to poll this.?

Comment: This is terrible for languages such as Python. Python does not allow inline snippets such as  `if condition: doSomething()`, which makes them really difficult to discuss in SO comments.

Comment: I was also looking for this and came across this thread. Just reading some of the responses which outright rejects this request\question is beyond my belief. How could you say that, one doesn't need a linebreak or formatted response? as the rest said, it's fairly important to add a comment using formatted text esp. when it comes to a code snippet.